# How to map and filter an object of arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data stored below. I want to filter cards based on title. I am implementing real time search in react on react-trello board but couldn't find a solution:

DATA:

```
  const data = {
  lanes: [
    {
      id: 'lane1',
      title: 'Planned Tasks',
      label: '2/2',
      cards: [
        {id: 'Card1', title: 'Write Blog', description: 'Can AI make memes', label: '30 mins', draggable: false},
        {id: 'Card2', title: 'Pay Rent', description: 'Transfer via NEFT', label: '5 mins', metadata: {sha: 'be312a1'}}
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 'lane2',
      title: 'Completed',
      label: '0/0',
      cards: []
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I have tried.

```
 const newData = data.lanes
    .map((lane) => {
      lane.cards.filter((card) => {
        return card.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
      });
    })
    .flat();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: `map` callback isn't returning anything. `filter` returns a new array and doesn't change the array in place

Comment: @VLAZ I need same shape as original but filtered as per my search query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply forgot to `return` inside the call to `map` (ie the result of `filter`):

```js
const data = {
  lanes: [
    {
      id: 'lane1',
      title: 'Planned Tasks',
      label: '2/2',
      cards: [
        {id: 'Card1', title: 'Write Blog', description: 'Can AI make memes', label: '30 mins', draggable: false},
        {id: 'Card2', title: 'Pay Rent', description: 'Transfer via NEFT', label: '5 mins', metadata: {sha: 'be312a1'}}
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 'lane2',
      title: 'Completed',
      label: '0/0',
      cards: []
    }
  ]
}

const search = "Write"

const newData = data.lanes
    .map((lane) => {
      return lane.cards.filter((card) => {
        return card.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
      });
    })
    .flat();
    
console.log(newData);
```

If you want the original shape of data with only lanes with matching cards

```js
const data = {
  lanes: [
    {
      id: 'lane1',
      title: 'Planned Tasks',
      label: '2/2',
      cards: [
        {id: 'Card1', title: 'Write Blog', description: 'Can AI make memes', label: '30 mins', draggable: false},
        {id: 'Card2', title: 'Pay Rent', description: 'Transfer via NEFT', label: '5 mins', metadata: {sha: 'be312a1'}}
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 'lane2',
      title: 'Completed',
      label: '0/0',
      cards: []
    }
  ]
}

const search = "Write"

const cardMatch = card => card.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) 

const newData = data.lanes
    .map(lane => ({...lane, cards: lane.cards.filter(cardMatch)}))
    .filter(lane => lane.cards.length > 0)
    
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: What a silly mistake. How can I get data with all lanes but with filtered cards. If lane does not have card it should still show up in data with its details

Comment: @MusadiqKhan so you want the same shape of data as the original, but only showing cards which match ?

Comment: @MusadiqKhan did you see my answer update?

Comment: @Jamiec- Although it did not solve my issue but it gave me a direction. Hence, I am accepting it as an answer.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you want the lane data, with applicable nested cards, try:

```
const search = 'rent';

const newLaneData = data.lanes
    .filter(lane => lane.cards
        .filter(card => card.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())).length > 0);
newLaneData.forEach(function(lane){
     lane.cards = lane.cards
          .filter(card => card.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()));
 });
```

If you just want the cards, try:

```
const newCardData = data.lanes
    .map(lane => lane.cards)
    .flat()
    .filter(card => card.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: @Tame I would like to get data with all lanes but with filtered cards.